# Access local Google Cloud Storage files in browser with filename instead of key

Tags: google-app-engine

In Google App Engine (GAE), files that get stored to the local Cloud Storage show up in the admin console with a path. Example:

> /gs/myapp.appspot.com.somefile.jpg

This one seems to get closer:

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:somefile.jpg

But that generates an error:

> Error 404 ApplicationError: 6: Could not read blob.

This one works but it requires I know the key:

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_key:some_key

Is there a way to use the local url but use the filename instead of a key?

Comment: Note that the `/_ah` paths are used internally by GAE and this particular example may be simply the internal development server implementation and *might* not work in production. You should use the recommended GCS client libraries to access/serve the files.

Comment: I'm only using this for development and my post only applies to local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go through the details of this [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/duythinht/a08a2c17f3b122ae5a1b) Code about how to read and write blobs. The code confirms that for image files, you always require the keys.

For Images, you require the Key http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:[Keys]

While for other files:  https://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/default_bucket/file_name